# Filling space with an <a> and centering it vertically

Tags: css

I'm trying to do a navigation bar using a table, here's the code right now:

```css
.nav-bar a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="nav-bar" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="historia.htm">História</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="local.htm">Localização</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="direto.htm">Direto</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="contactos.htm">Contactos</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that the text gets sent upwards, like shown here:

[image]

Comment: you may need to use another display for a or use pseudos to fill the empty part. Can you finalyze the snippet i updated , so we all see here what is your issue ? so we can help you  efficiently

Comment: ditch the table and use flex

Comment: I agree with @DominicTobias tables should only be used for showing data in most cases. I always make my navbars with a `ul > li > a` structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Using padding**

```css
.nav-bar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
  background: lightgrey;
}

table {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<table class="nav-bar" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="historia.htm">História</a></td>
    <td><a href="local.htm">Localização</a></td>
    <td><a href="direto.htm">Direto</a></td>
    <td><a href="contactos.htm">Contactos</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**2. Flexbox**
- no table

```css
.nav-bar a {
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.nav-bar {
  background: grey;
  display: flex; /* use inline-flex if you don't want it to strech the whole row */
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <a href="historia.htm">História</a>
  <a href="local.htm">Localização</a>
  <a href="direto.htm">Direto</a>
  <a href="contactos.htm">Contactos</a>
</div>
```

---

on a sidenote, please provide more details if you want a more accurate solution. are you adding height to the navbar or not? do you want it to strech the whole row, or just use only as much as needed?

Comment: Yeah, the flexbox solution might be the best option, easier to work with than a table tbf. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to vertically center your text in your navbar, I believe what you're looking for is to set **`line-height`** equal to `height`. Note that a percentage-based `line-height` is relative to font-size. If you don't explicitly set a font-size, a percentage-based `line-height` won't work ;)

```
.nav-bar a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%; /* relative to font-size */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: line-height:100%; will take font-size value as reference , not the height of the container

Answer (score 0):

You can center one line of text vertically by changing the line height to fill the vertical space:

```
.nav-bar a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```